# Undefined property: mysqli

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I am having a problem with the get data as its giving an error. And  Also Show Another Error

> Severity: Notice
>   Message: Trying to get property of non-object
>   Filename: views/view_school.php
>   Line Number: 121

Please help Me I am New in Codeignitor .......

> Severity: Notice
>   Message: Undefined property: mysqli::$firstname
>   Filename: views/view_school.php
>   Line Number: 121

Backtrace:

** Here Is My Conroller Code**

```
 public function index($offset = 0)
{

    $data['_pagecontent']="view_school";
    /*$data['sidebar']="schoolview";*/
    $limit = 10;
    $result = $this->AllSchoolModel->get_school($limit, $offset);
    $data['schools'] = $result['rows'];
    $data['num_results'] = $result['num_rows'];
    // load pagination library
    $this->load->library('pagination');
    $config = array();
    $config['base_url'] = site_url("AllSchool/index");
    $config['total_rows'] = $data['num_results'];
    $config['per_page'] = $limit;
    //which uri segment indicates pagination number
    $config['uri_segment'] = 3;
    $config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;
    //max links on a page will be shown
    $config['num_links'] = 5;
    $config['full_tag_open'] = '<ul class="pagination">';
    $config['full_tag_close'] = '</ul>';
    $config['num_tag_open'] = '<li class="page-item">';
    $config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['cur_tag_open'] = '<li class="page-item active"><a class="page-link" href="#">';
    $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</a></li>';
    $config['next_tag_open'] = '<li class="page-item">';
    $config['next_tagl_close'] = '</a></li>';
    $config['prev_tag_open'] = '<li class="page-item">';
    $config['prev_tagl_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['first_tag_open'] = '<li class="page-item disabled">';
    $config['first_tagl_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['last_tag_open'] = '<li class="page-item">';
    $config['last_tagl_close'] = '</a></li>';
    $config['attributes'] = array('class' => 'page-link');
    $this->pagination->initialize($config);
    $data['links'] = $this->pagination->create_links();
    $this->load->view('MainContent',$data);
}
```

**Here Is My Model Code**

```
    private $blogs = 'userregistration';
    function get_school($limit, $offset) 
    {
        if ($offset > 0) {
            $offset = ($offset - 1) * $limit;
        }
        $result['rows'] = $this->db->get($this->blogs, $limit, $offset);
        $result['num_rows'] = $this->db->count_all_results($this->blogs);
        return $result;
    }
```

**Here Is My View**

```
                  <table class="table datatable-basic">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>

                                <th>First Name</th>


                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>

                            <?php 
                             if( !empty($schools) ) {
                                  foreach($schools as $rowss)
                                 {  
                                ?>
                            <tr>

                                <td><?php echo $rowss->firstname;?></td>


                            </tr>
                            <?php
                                }
                            }
                            ?>

                        </tbody>
                    </table>
```

Comment: `print_r($data['schools'])` in your controller what does it yield?

Comment: make sure  `$schools` have column `firstname`

Comment: replace this  `$result = $this->AllSchoolModel->get_school($limit, $offset);`  with it  `$result = $this->AllSchoolModel->get_school($config['per_page'], $config['uri_segment']);`